# Dynamically adding song tag in yahoo web player in not working

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-widgets

I am using Yahoo web player and certain steps in order to add song to yahoo web player playlist.

1. I am displaying list of songs.
2. On click on a song creating a dynamic song url using jquery and appending in the `div` tag.
   Link Like: `<a href="http://www.example.com/data?v=yaariyaan"> Song </a>`
3. I want add this link to yahoo web player playlist.
   Code:

   ```
   fileUrl = "<a href='http://www.example.com/data?v=yaariyaan'> Song </a>";
   YAHOO.MediaPlayer.addTracks(fileUrl, 0, true);
   YAHOO.MediaPlayer.play();
   ```

`addTracks` is not adding the link to the playlist.

I am also getting the error:

> Error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fadeIn' of undefined ";

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the only way I could resolve it is to make the autoplay set to true, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var YMPParams = 
{
   autoplay:true
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/latest"></script>
```